# Py to exe with pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pyinstaller

I want to create a .exe out of a main.py file.
The script uses 2 external folder:
-ffmpeg folder with the ffmpeg .exe
-bunch of .mp3 files

When i try create the .exe file with pyinstaller, it goes fine but the program doesn't recognize these folders.How can i do to include these folders?

Pyinstaller command:

```
pyinstaller main.py -F --add-data "songs\;songs\" --add-data "ffmpeg\;ffmpeg\;" -n Msg -w
```

The script also uses the awscli pip package, but pyinstaller doesn't include it in the .exe(all the packages are installed in my venv).

Someone can help me?

EDIT:

I use AudioSegment to access .mp3 files: `AudioSegment.from_mp3(os.path.join("songs", song))`

To use ffmpeg i give this command that locate ffmpeg .exe file: `os.path.join(os.sep,"ffmpeg","bin")`

Both folders are in the same directory of the main.py file:

```
|main folder
--|main.py
--|songs
---|.mp3 files
--|ffmpeg
---|bin
----|ffmpeg .exe file
```

Comment: Can you provide at least a few lines of code showing how you access the folders. Also provide the actual build command with no typo please

Comment: I use Audiosegement to work with .mp3 files and this is the code i Use both for import ffmpeg and .mp3 files.                                                                            AudioSegment.ffmpeg = os.path.join(os.sep,"ffmpeg","bin") -->access to ffmpeg .exe    AudioSegment.from_mp3(os.path.join("songs", song)) -->access to songs

Comment: Your pyinstaller build command indicates you want to pack songs and ffmpeg in the exe. Is it really what you want? Also there seems to be some typo, like the second "\;" from ffmpeg. You should review the build log if the command you are providing is the actual one you are using. Also can you provide the error or behaviour that leads you to state "the program doesn't recognize these folders" ?

Comment: There's no output error:when I open the program I have to choose from a list of songs but the list is empty,so the files aren't recognized.For ffmpeg cmd shows 'ffmpeg not recognized' message.

Comment: can you please answer all the questions from my various comments please.

Comment: Providing the piece of code where you build th list of songs to choose from will also be helpful

Comment: Any update with your issue ?

Answer (score 1):

Based on documentation here: https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html, you'll need to use a spec file.

If the package is in your venv, you should run the PyInstaller inside your enviroment.